# Blazor WASM Client Not Connecting to Server Controller (deployed instance

Tags: blazor, webassembly

Have taken a simple, out-of-the-box Blazor WASM project (the default Home/Counter/FetchData example) and deployed to a hosted server.

This same solution runs fine locally (e.g. counter works and fetch data page calls the server controller) and the server framework is 3.1.

However, when running the deployed version, the fetch data page never returns data (stuck on 'Loading...')

My guess is the client assembly (named 'BW_Test.Client.dll' and located in the \root\home\user1-001\www\site1\wwwroot_framework_bin\ folder) cannot find the server controller.

Initially thought my issue was that I needed to add app.UsePathBase to startup.cs, but either that's not the answer or what I've tried ("/") isn't correct.

Suggestions?

Comment: Found a solution on another site that works though I don't fully understand it.

Had to add an additional attribute to the controller ([Route("api/[controller]")]).

Then had to modify startup.cs as follows:
Replace default MapFallbackToFile("index.html") with  
- endpoints.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);
- endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug}", "index.html");

And the api call was changed to 'api/WeatherForecast'.

Is this needed because it needs to run off of a different port or does anyone know?